# How to convert firebase storage image to a File object in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I have uploaded an image into my FirebaseFirestore. When I re-download the image from the downloadUrl it downloads as an Image object, is there any way to get this is as a File object instead?

Comment: Aren't you getting a file object? You can display the image using Image.File()

Comment: You are exactly correct. Turns out I had been accustom to having the URL as a string and placing that in the network image object. Thank you for shaking me awake on this one!

Comment: You're welcome. I also had the same problem before. Glad it helps. Good Luck in your project :)